# Is the 100 ohm resistor needed in this mains power supply?

Tags: circuit-design, circuit-protection

Do I need the 100 ohm resistor in the below circuit? Is there any problem if I don't use it?

[image: wiring diagram]

Comment: What are you going to use this for? Are you aware that the **DC Out 12 V** will be **live**?

Comment: For 12v led strip

Comment: you could get a bridge and capacitor damaging inrush current. You should use at least an X2 for that mains connected cap.

Comment: Those 12 V strips generally don't have adequate insulation to protect the user from electric shock. You need an isolated power supply for that so this one is not suitable. I suspect that you haven't worked out what current you need. That will be a problem with this power supply too. Get a proper 12 V isolated PSU with an adequate current rating.

Comment: If you're asking that, then you should not be building transformerless power supplies until you know more. They're dangerous.

Comment: @Suny  This is Sunny.  What is your real problem and real load?  ( Hot parts ?)

Comment: Death trap 101!

Comment: Not if enclosed properly for some load TBD?

Comment: You are not explaining in 4?5? questions how you are misusing this circuit..  If Zener is too low power and no load, then it can fuse open, then Cap fails out from over voltage and shorts,but hot resistor is normal if open and abnormal if safely enclosed but then improperly derated for temp rise.

Comment: It is very safe unless you make an error in completing the design correctly

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 No, this is not "very safe". It is **very unsafe**. There is no isolation between mains and the output -- at 220V it's an absolute death trap.

Comment: @Clipboard_Waving_Enginerd "Most likely" is not a very good comment when there are lethal voltages involved. When questions like this show a general lack of knowledge we try to err on the side of safety with our comments and answers, as you can see from those who followed you.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Good point thank you.  I deleted the comment.
To Suny  you could use one of the ubiquitous 12V power bricks everyone has a drawer full of.  Better yet buy a 12V supply for the LED strip, [Use this question as your guide.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you need it.

If you don't have it, some part of your circuit will burn out and be destroyed.  Which part will actually go "poof" or "bang" first can't really be predicted.

---

[You've been told before,](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/446311/resistor-capacitor-are-getting-too-hot) but I'm going to tell you again:

That circuit can **kill** you.

You must operate that thing in an enclosed box.

Do **not** allow any user to touch any electrical part of that thing when it is operating.

If you connect the output of that thing to another device, then **that** device can now kill you, and should be enclosed when operating.

You **must** assume all parts of that thing to be at line voltage.

You should find a safer powersupply circuit to build.

Comment: To elaborate... You need it because it is limiting inrush current. When you plug this in and the capacitors are empty, they will act as short circuits until they are full. That 100ohm resistor limits that initial current spike.


PS. This will kill you.

Comment: @Stiddily:  That resistor is **constantly** limiting current.  An earlier question from the same person asks why that 5 watt resistor is getting too hot to touch.  So, it isn't **just** the inrush current.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of PACKAGING INFO that you are **not telling us** that lead up to your overheating failures.  All parts serve a different purpose.

But with the right parts, in the right thermally convection air-cooled, but double-insulated behind the wall along with your LEDs or loads out of harm's way, **it can be safe**, but packaging design is not shown. I suspect with the care taken in your schematic, that the heat-rise in packaging lead to cascaded infant failures.

*If done wrong such as reversing line and Neutral and touch LED "0V", or common mode transient... poof! zap!.*

[This shows you the actual REACTIVE and REAL power of each part.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000014999999999999999%20146.80153516788286%2050%205%2048%0Av%2096%20336%2096%2048%200%201%2050%20325%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20224%2048%20224%20112%200%0Ad%20224%20112%20288%20176%203%20default%0Ad%20224%20240%20288%20176%203%20default%0Ad%20160%20176%20224%20112%203%20default%0Ad%20160%20176%20224%20240%203%20default%0Aw%20224%20240%20224%20336%200%0Aw%20160%20176%20160%20272%200%0Aw%20288%20176%20336%20176%200%0Aw%20160%20272%20336%20272%200%0Aw%20336%20176%20416%20176%200%0Aw%20336%20272%20416%20272%200%0Ax%20670%20226%20700%20229%204%2016%20load%0Ar%2096%20336%20224%20336%200%20100%0A34%20default-zener12%200%201.7143528192810002e-7%202%202%2012%0Az%20336%20272%20336%20176%202%20default-zener12%0A403%20240%2032%20368%2096%200%201_64_0_28929_0.0001_0.22396393933121672_0_2_1_3%0A403%20288%20112%20416%20176%200%208_64_0_12546_12.362113060073211_0.0001_0_2_8_3%0Ag%20336%20272%20336%20288%200%0Ac%2096%2048%20224%2048%200%200.0000022%20-149.51746925620301%0A209%20416%20176%20416%20256%200%200.00047%2012.352365609704558%201%0A403%2096%20-32%20224%2032%200%2018_64_7_20738_640_0.1_0_1_80%0A403%20-64%20128%2064%20192%200%200_8_0_4610_640_0.00009765625_0_2_0_3%0A403%2096%20352%20224%20416%200%2013_64_7_12546_0.0001_0.0001_0_1_5.0159846120756955%0A403%20256%20336%20384%20400%200%2014_64_7_12546_0.0001_0.0001_0_1_1.7076495874458584%0A403%20448%20112%20576%20176%200%2019_64_7_4354_20_0.1_0_1_2.5%0Ar%20416%20256%20416%20272%200%200.1%0A403%20464%20208%20592%20272%200%2025_16_7_20738_0.01953125_0.1_0_1_0.00244140625%0A34%20default-ledW%200%209.32e-11%2015%206%203%0A162%20720%20176%20720%20208%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20736%20176%20736%20208%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20752%20176%20752%20208%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20800%20176%20800%20208%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20784%20176%20784%20208%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20768%20176%20768%20208%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20768%20208%20768%20240%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20784%20208%20784%20240%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20800%20208%20800%20240%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20752%20208%20752%20240%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20736%20208%20736%20240%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20720%20208%20720%20240%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20720%20272%20720%20304%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20736%20272%20736%20304%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20752%20272%20752%20304%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20800%20272%20800%20304%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20784%20272%20784%20304%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20768%20272%20768%20304%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20768%20240%20768%20272%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20784%20240%20784%20272%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20800%20240%20800%20272%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20752%20240%20752%20272%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20736%20240%20736%20272%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0A162%20720%20240%20720%20272%202%20default-ledW%201%201%201%200.02%0Aw%20800%20176%20784%20176%200%0Aw%20784%20176%20768%20176%200%0Aw%20768%20176%20752%20176%200%0Aw%20752%20176%20736%20176%200%0Aw%20736%20176%20720%20176%200%0Aw%20800%20304%20784%20304%200%0Aw%20784%20304%20768%20304%200%0Aw%20768%20304%20752%20304%200%0Aw%20752%20304%20736%20304%200%0Aw%20736%20304%20720%20304%200%0Aw%20720%20304%20416%20272%200%0Aw%20720%20176%20416%20176%202%0A403%20-64%20224%2064%20288%200%200_8_7_21250_640_0.1_0_1_40%0A403%20-64%2048%2064%20112%200%200_16_0_4353_640_0.4_0_2_0_3%0Ao%208%2064%200%204353%20320%203.2%200%202%208%203%0Ao%208%2064%200%204354%20160%200.1%201%202%208%203%0A)
[image]

This design lacks:

- thermal packaging, electrical insulation design
- PLT Power Line Transient protection.
- fusing
- technical analysis and adequate engineering details in question

But still can be made to work!